# Hold a keyboard key to turn a left click into a right click

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, touchpad, right-click

Ok, guys. I have a Logitech touch pad that I'm using with Windows. There are some games (Diablo 3 mostly) that heavily use the mouse's right and left clicks. It's not convenient for me to constantly tap with two fingers on the touch pad to right click while I'm gaming.

What I'm looking for is a way to assign a key on the keyboard, so that when it is held down and I left click with the touchpad, its actually a right click.

I don't want to assign the right click to a key. I want that key to modify my left click. It's basically the way you used to have to CMD+click on Mac to right click.

Answer (score 1):

My good sir, you need AutoHotKey.  Install it and run this script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad ;Change Notepad to whatever class/program you need, or remove this line entirely and it will work with all programs.
LControl & LButton::
Send {RButton}  ;send Right Click
```

http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: Good call, occasionally there can be issues with this, good reading here: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/111737-how-to-make-ahk-work-in-most-games-the-basics/